# string decode utf-8

Tags: java, android

How can I decode an utf-8 string with android? I tried with this commands but output is the same of input:

```
URLDecoder.decode("hello&//à", "UTF-8");

new String("hello&//à", "UTF-8");

EntityUtils.toString("hello&//à", "utf-8");
```

Comment: That String is not in a particular encoding at all. What is it, the problem which you're trying to solve? What exactly do you mean with "decode"? What encoding was it in, did you think?

Comment: try using a local variable to hold the result. Ex: String str = URLDecoder.decode("hello&//à", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A string needs no encoding. It is simply a sequence of Unicode characters.

You need to *encode* when you want to turn a String into a sequence of bytes. The charset the you choose (UTF-8, cp1255, etc.) determines the Character->Byte mapping. Note that a character is not necessarily translated into a single byte. In most charsets, most Unicode characters are translated to at least two bytes.

Encoding of a String is carried out by:

```
String s1 = "some text";
byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Charset to encode into
```

You need to *decode* when         you have а sequence of bytes and you want to turn them into a String. When yоu dо that you need to specify, again, the charset with which the bytеs were originally encoded (otherwise you'll end up with garblеd tеxt).

Decoding:

```
String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // Charset with which bytes were encoded
```

If you want to understand this better, a great text is "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"

Answer (score 10):

the core functions are `getBytes(String charset)` and `new String(byte[] data)`. you can use these functions to do UTF-8 decoding.

UTF-8 decoding actually is a string to string conversion, the intermediate buffer is a byte array. since the target is an UTF-8 string, so the only parameter for `new String()` is the byte array, which calling is equal to `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`

Then the key is the parameter for input encoded string to get internal byte array, which you should know beforehand. If you don't, guess the most possible one, "ISO-8859-1" is a good guess for English user.

The decoding sentence should be

```
String decoded = new String(encoded.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Not clear, how incomplete multibyte UTF8 chunks are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [decode string encoded in utf-8 format in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828091/decode-string-encoded-in-utf-8-format-in-android) but it doesn't look like your string is encoded with anything particular. What do you think the output should be?