# Spring Web - decoding URL params

Tags: java, spring, url, web-applications, encoding

I have a spring based web application running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.39 and get request that contains parameter values having special characters (UTF-8 encoded).

For example:

```
street=R%C3%BCbenkamp+246
```

I need to pass this values to a DB lookup but first decode them.
How shall I do it?

I tried:

```
URLDecoder.decode(street, "UTF-8");
```

but it seems that the value stays the same after decoding...

Comment: This should help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943152/string-decode-utf-8

Comment: unfortunately, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that really helped was modifying Tomcat server.xml and adding the URIEncoding="UTF-8" to the connector settings (my WS runs on port 8181)

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```