# Garbled in the JSP page created in JAVA

Tags: java, file, jsp, stringbuilder

I use myeclipse development software, the default encoding is utf-8, when I created JSP in java, there is a Chinese chaos phenomenon. I have been working back and forth for a long time and have not solved this problem. Can someone help me?  After the successful establishment of jsp, the Chinese displayed inside becomes garbled.

```
public  void CreatHtml(String filePath){


        StringBuilder stringHtml = new StringBuilder();


        PrintStream printStream =null;

       try {
       printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath),true,"UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}


        stringHtml.append("<html><head>");
        stringHtml.append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
        stringHtml.append("<title>测试报告文档</title>");
        stringHtml.append("</head>");
        stringHtml.append("<body>");

        stringHtml.append("<h1>简单快速用Java动态生成jsp/html页面</h1>");
        stringHtml.append("</body></html>");
        try{

            printStream.println(stringHtml.toString());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



        public String execute(){


        String imgname =UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jsp";
        System.out.println(imgname);

        String filePath = "d:\\MyEclipseWork\\gxAppWebServer\\WebRoot\\"+imgname;

        CreatHtml(filePath);


        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: yep, that happens, search for BalusC utf8

Comment: This question is very poorly written. A code example should be provided alongside the error/exception which is being outputted.

Comment: <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>æµè¯æ¥åææ¡£</title></head><body><h1>ç®åå¿«éç¨Javaå¨æçæjsp/htmlé¡µé¢</h1></body></html> The Chinese inside has become garbled

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with your meta tag. Please replace your meta tag with below :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: stringHtml.append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset="utf-8"\">")   ，  this will report an error.  error(The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int)

Comment: CreatHtml method is part of your jsp or servlet code?

Comment: Not，charset="utf-8" ， I added it or not. this is Java class

Comment: Replace your meta line with stringHtml.append("<meta charset=\"utf-8\"> ");

Comment: <html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>æµè¯æ¥åææ¡£</title></head><body><h1>ç®åå¿«éç¨Javaå¨æçæjsp/htmlé¡µé¢</h1></body></html>                 Still like this

Comment: The issue is with encode/decode of chars. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943152/string-decode-utf-8