# Error while adding a new utf8 string column to Row in Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add a new column in each row of DataFrame like this

```
  def addNamespace(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
    iter.map (row => {
      println(row.getString(0))
//      Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[String]("shared"))

      val newseq = row.toSeq ++ Array[String]("shared")
      Row(newseq: _*)
    })
    iter
  }

  def transformDf(source: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val newSchema = StructType(source.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("namespace", StringType, nullable = true)))
    val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(source.rdd.mapPartitions(addNamespace), newSchema)
    df.show()
    df

  }
```

But I keep getting this error - `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String is not a valid external type for schema of string` on the line `df.show()`

Can somebody please help in figuring out this. I have searched around in multiple posts but whatever I have tried is giving me this error.

I have also tried `val again = sourceDF.withColumn("namespace", functions.lit("shared"))` but it has the same issue.

Schema of already read data

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- activates_on: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- expires_on: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created_by: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created_on: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_by: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_on: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the actual data. Check for special characters, backslashes and spaces. Even if one of the record has this issue, you won't be able to create the dataframe. The error means - actual data is not in line with the sort of data you should provide for a String type.

Comment: @Anamdeo I am reading data from Cassandra and want to add a new column of StringType which has a fixed string value. So even if I have some special characters in already read data, I won't be able to create the dataframe?

Comment: Can you print the schema of already read data and paste it here.

Comment: @Anamdeo updated the already read schema in the questions

Comment: @Anamdeo is right see my answer and solution for this.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I don't understand your solution, I'm having the same error, can you post your solution instead of linking to other SOs

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String is not a valid external type
>   for schema of string

means its unable to understand as string type... for newly added  "namespace" column.

***Clearly indicates datatype mismatch error at catalyst level...***

see spark code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/objects/objects.scala#L1714)..

```
override def eval(input: InternalRow): Any = {
    val result = child.eval(input)
    if (checkType(result)) {
      result
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"${result.getClass.getName}$errMsg")
    }
  }
```

and error message is [`s" is not a valid external type for schema of ${expected.catalogString}"`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/objects/objects.scala#L1695)

So UTF String is not real string you need to encode/decode it before passing it as string type otherwise catalyst will not able to understand what you are passing.

> *How to fix it ?*

Below are the SO content which will address how to encode/decode to/from utfstring to string and viceversa... you may need to apply suitable solution for this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943395/647053
[string decode utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943152/string-decode-utf-8)

***Note :***
This [online UTF-8 encoder/decoder tool](https://mothereff.in/utf-8)    is very handy to put sample data and convert that to string. try this first....

Comment: Hello. It sounds useful. Haven't got chance to try it. I will try it once I get some time and update. thanks!