# How to Decode String in Android?

Tags: android, decode

I have a parser module in my application which will parse the response from a webservice and give the tag value. The tag value contains some special characters like ® etc. The problem is I could not decode the special characters to normal string. please find the sample response string below,

```
Apple&#174; iPad&#153; Case
```

Please some body help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Look at this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828091/decode-string-encoded-in-utf-8-format-in-android

Comment: @Rajapandian: Suggestion: If you want to use these special characters to show on screen only, then you can use them in a web page (in HTML), and then show that web page in web view. This way, those characters will be automatically rendered properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4882425/1224741

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a faster way to decode html characters to a string than Html.fromHtml()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321896/is-there-a-faster-way-to-decode-html-characters-to-a-string-than-html-fromhtml)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Answer (score 6):

Just Use `String result = URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");`

Or use this

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this

```
String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(your string, "UTF-8");
```