# Android parse XML which uses &lt; and &gt; instead of "<" and ">"

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I'm using a WEB service which return XML format but with `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of "<" and ">".

Now I dont know how to parse it?

I tried the standard **SAX parser:**

```
if (entity != null && responseCode==200) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader rd = null;             
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                InputSource is=new InputSource(rd);
                WebServiceRespondParser parser=new WebServiceRespondParser(category);
                SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp=factory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader reader=sp.getXMLReader();
                reader.setContentHandler(parser);
                reader.parse(is);   
                markers=parser.getMarkers();
        }
```

**WEB service:**

http://gisn.tel-aviv.gov.il/ws_iriya_zmina/wsgis.asmx/GetData4TargetLayersFromAddress?Format=xml&TargetIriaLayerIDs=659&Radiuses=2000&Rechov=798&Bayit=3&Knisa=

I read few similar question, but most are in different languages, or doesn't have answer.

Comment: that is a pretty odd way of returning XML data...

Comment: Can you, please, explain why?

Comment: It's an XML document stored as text inside another XML document... Who thought this was a good idea?

Comment: I agree with you.. But that's what I got, and what I need to use..;)

Comment: I am not saying you did anything wrong. I am saying the web service is weird.

Comment: It's all cool.. Tnx for contributing.. ;)

Comment: Use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html) as answered in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828091/decode-string-encoded-in-utf-8-format-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That XML is encoded because it's inside the  tag. What you need to do is to first parse the original XML, then get the value from the  tag. This will get you the proper XML that you can now parse as usual.

Comment: So you mean to parse this xml I got from Web service - this one child, and than to parse that child as new xml?

Comment: If it is so, I still dont know how to do it.. :) If I try to parse it with SAX parser `@Override public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)` I don't get this all inside data, just the one character..

Comment: Of course, you have to save the string one by one. When you reach an `endElement` you can then save the resulting string somewhere. Return that and then create a new SAX parser implementation to parse that.

Comment: Since you're using sax parser you'll probably have to unescape the text your self.