# Android parse this: &lt;layer&gt; &lt;irial... as XML

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml with `&lt;` and `&gt;` as a String variable. Now I need to parse it like an XML , preferably using SAX parser.

I'm not sure how should I do it. If I call `SAX` parser with this string it wont give me nothing.

Comment: It looks like you just accepted an answer on the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145633/android-parse-xml-which-uses-lt-and-gt-instead-of-and) a couple hours ago.

Comment: If you read more carefully you will see this is different problem. This one is more specific.

Comment: Actually, the answer is pretty much the same: you'll need to **unescape** the text first and then feed it to the XML parser. Simply use one of the available helper libraries 'out there', e.g. Apache Commons' [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hey.. Tnx for the suggestion.. Unescape wont work because String is way too big. I tried...  But what I did was String.replace and it worked.. As simple as that..:)