# How to deal with checked exception (UnsupportedEncodingException) that can never occurs?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying transform  a string to UTF-8 encoding. But the compilation fails because some code "throws UnsupportedEncodingException".

```
String s = "1,2,3,4";
String smsext = new String(s.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception `UnsupportedEncodingException` is thrown by the String constructor (not by Android Studio !!!). This is a checked exception and so your code must handle it in some way.

**In this particular case** : the exception will never be thrown because "UTF-8" is hardcoded and always supported by any JVM (this is a requirement). So you can catch it silently :

```
String s = "1,2,3,4";
String smsext = null;
try{
    smsext = new String(s.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    //can never occurs
}
```

**But I don't recommend this over simplistic approach** because silently catching an exception is almost always a very bad practice. A more appropriate solution for catched exception that *never append* is to rethrow the exception encapsulated in an unchecked exception :

```
String s = "1,2,3,4";
String smsext = null;
try{
    smsext = new String(s.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    //can never occurs because UTF-8 is always supported
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

With this code, if one day you change the body of the try-catch block so that UnsupportedEncodingException can possibly occurs : the exception won't be ignored silently.

Comment: right,I forget try{}catch{},so that throws this UnsupportedEncodingException.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the String constructor with the charset paramete (with try{}catch{}), take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828257/4224337)